# Update an ES6 Arrow Function such that it works on IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, arrow-functions

I am stuck on making this polyfill code for IE which has the following code running.

```
var filterArrayGAME = $("#locGAME span").get().map(el => el.textContent)
```

Is there a way to write this in such a manner that we do not encounter an issue while trying to view this page on Internet Explorer ?

Comment: so use a function.... `(function (el) { return el.textContent; })` .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Babel.js to convert your ES6 code to ES5 code Which is supported by the IE browser.

Babel is a toolchain that is mainly used to convert ECMAScript 2015+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript in current and older browsers or environments.

Here is the conversion done by Babel:

```
var filterArrayGAME = $("#locGAME span").get().map(function (el) {
  return el.textContent;
});
```

Reference:

[Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/)